# How to create a convex hull set polygons conditioned by a minimum number of points and a maximum distance

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator, convex-hull

With the following expression I am trying to create a set of convex hulls from a layer with a point geometry that complies two variable conditions: a minimum number of points can be declared and a maximum distance can be declared.

My first approximation to get these goal is the following expression. In this work example case, the minimum number of points is 6 and the maximum distance is 200 meters:

```
convex_hull(
    collect_geometries(
        array_foreach(
            array_filter(
                overlay_nearest('punts', $geometry, limit:=6, max_distance:=200),
                distance($geometry, @element) > (
                    array_sort(
                        array_agg(
                            distance($geometry, @element)
                        )
                    )[1] * 3
                )
            ),
            @element
        )
    )
)
```

Expression description:

My idea to create a convex hull with a variable number of nearest points and a maximum distance I use `overlay_nearest` function in combinaction with `convex_hull` function and a expression to calculate the minimum distance. Here are the steps:

1- `limit:=6` → variable to number of nearest points I want to consider

2- `max_distance:=200` → variable to the maximum distance I want to consider

3- `[1] * 3` → variable to minimum distance factor I want to use

I write this expression with the idea to works by first using the `overlay_nearest` function to finds specified number of nearest points to each feature in the layer within the specified maximum distance. I then filters out any points that are closer than specified minimum distance factor using `array_filter` function and the distance function. Finally, it collects all the filtered points into single multipoint geometry and creates a convex hull polygon.

Result of the previous expression in which I have made a correction in adding the `max_distance` parameter:

[image]

Then I add the conditions like this but with this expression the result is NULL:

```
CASE
WHEN count(overlay_nearest('punts', $geometry, limit:=6, max_distance:=200)) >= 6 THEN
convex_hull(collect_geometries(array_foreach(generate_series(1,6), 
convex_hull(
    collect_geometries(
        array_foreach(
            array_filter(
                overlay_nearest('punts',$geometry,limit:=6, max_distance:=200),
                distance($geometry, @element) > (
                    array_sort(
                        array_agg(
                            distance($geometry, @element)
                        )
                    )[0] * 3
                )
            ),
            @element
        )
    )
))))
ELSE
NULL
END
```

Result of this expression after adding the correction proposed by user [Tom Brennan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/129409/tom-brennan):

[image]

So far the result is not as expected. I don't know if this approach is good, or if the problem I want to solve is not so trivial and requires a more sophisticated expression that takes into consideration a different approach. Any help is welcome.

The expected result would be something like this:

[image]

I don't know if I am approaching the problem well with this expression I am building, or there is some other more simplified approach.

Comment: Can you explain your first expression? It looks like you are saying that the distance to any feature in the group should be no more than 3 times the distance to the closest feature in that group, but you haven't mentioned this anywhere else. How does this relate to the 200m?

Comment: Yes, of course. I try to make the description of the expression in the text above

Comment: Start by replacing "count" with "array_length". I don't think it will fully solve your problem(!), but it will fix the reason that you're getting NULL for everything. "overlay_nearest" returns an array, so you need to test the length of the array.

Comment: I confirm that the NULL error is corrected. I add a screenshot of the obtained result but the result is not as expected. I guess my expression approach is not the right one.

Comment: The core issue you have is that each point feature will have its own convex hull (or NULL if it fails the test) because the initial logic is looking for the nearest 6 points to that point within 200m. Your final diagram assumes that you will only end up with say 4 convex hulls, but you can see from the previous diagram that it's potentially quite a few more than that. Your problem statement has similarities with: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/468119/aggregation-of-buffers-from-polygons

Comment: It is exactly as you explain it. My expression does not answer the goal because its design is not well thought out. Right now I'm stuck, I don't know where to go from here. I leave the question open in case someone would like to provide a solution. Thank you.

Comment: You probably need to refine your conditions more precisely, and also accept that it may be too hard to do with just the Geometry Generator ie may need to create a helper layer. For example, if you were to just restrict to a maximum distance between points, and a minimum number of points, you could use a buffer layer similar to the solution above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you split the workflow in two (three) steps:

1. Run [DB-Scan clustering](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html?highlight=clustering#dbscan-clustering) with you settings: Minimum of 6 points per cluster, within 200 m. I only got three clusters out of my random points, but that should suffice (green are points not in a cluster):
   [image]
2. Use the [minimum bounding geometry](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=minimum%20bounding%20geometry#minimum-bounding-geometry) tool, asking it to return convex hulls, and taking into account the `CLUSTER_ID` the DB-Scan gave us:
   [image]
3. Manually remove the largest convex hull, which covers all points.

You could automate this whole process using the graphical modeler, even allowing different cluster sizes and distances by requesting them as part of the model. The last step of removing the largest convex hull could be done by selecting and deleting the hull with the largest area.

Comment: Thanks Erik for this proposed solution but it is not what I am looking for

In my case (45 points cloud, the DBScan clustering algorithm with 6 min size points, and with 200 max distance, only returns me 1 cluster

On the other hand, I would like to solve this goal with the Styling Geometry Generator options to avoid preprocessing and data storage

Thanks anyway

Comment: I'm sorry if I did not explain myself well at the beginning of the question